# Derivative of a multivariable, piecewise function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I was asked to show that the function $h(t)=f(g(t))$ is differentiable at $t=0$, where

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq 0 \\ 0 & (x,y)=0 \end{cases}$

and $\vec{g}(t)=(kt,pt)$ for constants $k$ and $p$.

I made a diagram and said "$h$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, which are functions of $t$. Hence, $h'(t)=f_x(x,y)k+f_y(x,y)p$." I then plugged in $t=0$, which gave me $h'(0)=0$. (I had calculated $f_x$ and $f_y$ beforehand and found them to be $0$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.)

However, my answer is marked wrong and the correct answer is $\frac{k^2p}{k^2+p^2}$. Why am I wrong, and why is this the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that this is the correct answer, we compute the derivative from first principles

$$h'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{h(t)-h(0)}{t}$$
which reduces to
$$h'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{k^2pt^3}{k^2t^3+p^2t^3}=\frac{k^2p}{k^2+p^2}$$

The reason your calculation is wrong is because $f(x,y)$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, which is to say there doesn't exist a linear map $df_0$ such that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{||f(x,y)-f(0,0)-df_0(x,y)||}{||(x,y)||}=0$$

In the proof of chain rule, we use this fact, which is why chain rule doesn't apply here. Conceptually, this is saying the directionally derivative doesn't change in a "sensible" way, which we would need to be able to write it in terms of the partial derivatives

Answer (score 0):

$$f(g(t))=\frac{k^2p}{k^2+p^2}t$$
Though for $f(x,y)$ exists partial derivative $$f_x(x,y)=\frac{2xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, \space f_y(x,y)=\frac{x^4-x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$ they are not continuous in point $(0,0)$ and function is not differentiable, which comes, if we consider increment in point $(0,0)$ and take, for example, $(x,y)=(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$, then we have
$$\Delta f(0,0)=\frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Plugging $g$ in $f$ certainly makes it easier to see where the correct answer comes from. Thank you. But why is my solution wrong? In fact, if I were to generalize my solution for all values of $t$, it gives me $h’(t)=\nabla f(x,y)\cdot \vec{g}’(t)$. Why is this wrong?

Comment: @kerizthemathundergrad. Added detailed explanation for $f(x,y)$ behaviour in (0,0). I admit that someone have right not to like the answer and h/she has the right to be not thankful for it, but the answer is correct, the proof is provided in difference from the declaration and down vote for the difference in tastes is incorrect. At least there should be the courage of constructive criticism.